# Unable to enforce https for github pages with Godaddy domain

Tags: ssl, github, github-pages

GH-pages tells me the domain is not eligible for HTTPS at this time. I am wondering how do I enable this with a Godaddy purchased domain? My site is connected and running properly, but I cannot get HTTPS to work. I have also checked that there are no mixed-asset types in my index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that in the DNS records that are automatically configured with the GoDaddy domain, you must remove that A Record that has the value of `park`.

Comment: I don't see any A Record with Park value, still not able to enable HTTPS. Please help

Comment: Hey, I dealt with this a while ago, but that's what worked for me back then. Do you still need help?

Comment: Got resolved. It was a timing issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There will be 4 entries of A and 1 entry of CNAME. Remove the other entries with A and CNAME rest of the type of entries will remain there.

[image]